# Lightroom publish to Facebook: managing existing photos

Tags: lightroom, file-management, facebook

Is there any way to synchronize existing photos in a given album of a Facebook page with Lightroom's Facebook Publish services? I can add the developed photos to the Publish collection, but I have no comment/like synchronicity.

I.e. the original photo uploaded to Facebook was developed with Lightroom but uploaded directly through a browser, from hereon I'm thinking of publishing using Facebook.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience you can only upload photos to Facebook. Once they're there you can't manage them from lightroom. You have to login and managed them on Facebook.